# Assert expected exception with specific criteria in custom fields

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I want to verify that an expected exception meets certain criteria. Take this as a starting point:

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    int n;
    public MyException(String message, int n) {
        super(message);
        this.n = n;
    }
}

public class HowDoIDoThis {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        thrown.expect(MyException.class);
        throw new MyException("x", 10);
    }
}
```

How do I assert, for example, that the thrown exception has `n > 1` and `message` contains only lowercase letters? I was thinking of using `thrown.expect(Matcher)` but can't figure out how to get a Hamcrest matcher to check arbitrary fields of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeSafeMatcher` where you can provide your `MyException` class, and then an `IntPredicate` to check the `n` value against a condition:

```
public class MyExceptionMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<MyException> {
    private final IntPredicate predicate;

    public MyExceptionMatcher(IntPredicate predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(MyException item) {
        return predicate.test(item.n);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("my exception which matches predicate");
    }
}
```

Then you can expect like so:

```
thrown.expect(new MyExceptionMatcher(i -> i > 1));
```

Comment: Why is the constructor private?

Comment: Ok :) I thought it may have been some neat trick. I ended up creating a static initializer instead of changing the modifier.

Answer (score 3):

A consise and neat alternative way is to use AssertJ instead of the ExpectedException rule.

```
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        throw new MyException("x", 10);
    })
        .matches(e -> e.getMessage().equals(e.getMessage().toLower()), "message is lowercase")
        .matches(e -> ((CustomException) e).n > 10, "n > 10");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also `FeatureMatcher` in Hamcrest that is great for creating matchers for nested "features" of objects. So in your example, you could structure it using `FeatureMatcher` in the following way (this is the pattern I tend to follow when creating matchers for nested fields):

```
public final class MyExceptionMatchers {

    public static Matcher<MyException> withNthat(Matcher<Integer> nMatcher) {
        return new FeatureMatcher<MyException, Integer>(nMatcher, "n", "n") {
              @Override
              protected Integer featureValueOf(MyException actual) {
                   return actual.n;
              }
        }
    };
}
```

And in your test:

```
import static x.y.z.MyExceptionMatchers.withNthat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan;

...

thrown.expect(withNThat(greaterThan(1)));
```

With this layout it's very easy to add more matchers for `MyException` and it feels like a more "canonical" approach to build composable matchers that allow you to construct the exact matcher you want for your test case.